# delete from datatable without affecting checkbox event

Tags: jsf

I have a datatable in which first component is delete button and last is checkbox.
Now problem is that when I delete a row it reset the checkbox selected in other row
I dont want to uncheck the selected checkbox in other row.

```
<h:dataTable id="languageTableBody" value="#{countryBean.countryLanguageList}" var="countryLangObj" >
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msg['country.language.label.delete']}</f:facet>
             <p:commandLink action="#{countryBean.deleteRow}" immediate="true" update="@form" process="@this">
                <h:graphicImage value="../images/delete.png"  />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{countryBean.langId}" value="#{countryLangObj.language.languageCode}" />
             </p:commandLink>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msg['country.language.label.assignlanguage']}</f:facet>
            <h:inputText readonly="true" value="#{countryLangObj.language.languageName}" id="languageName" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msg['country.language.label.languagecode']}</f:facet>
            <h:inputText readonly="true" value="#{countryLangObj.language.languageCode}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msg['country.language.label.defaultlanguage']}</f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{countryLangObj.isDefaultLanguage}" onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this)" />

        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

countryBean.java

```
public String deleteRow(){
    System.out.println("deleteRow()::Enter");
    String delLangId = getLangId();
    System.out.println("getLangId(): "+getLangId());
    if(null != delLangId && delLangId.trim().length() > 0){
        System.out.println("Delete Language Code: "+delLangId);
        List<CountryLanguageDTO> countryLangList = getCountryLanguageList();
        System.out.println("countryLangList: "+ (null == countryLangList));
        List<CountryLanguageDTO> tempCountryLangList = new ArrayList<CountryLanguageDTO>();
        for (CountryLanguageDTO countryLanguage : countryLangList) {
            System.out.println("wewewewew: "+delLangId.equalsIgnoreCase(countryLanguage.getLanguage().getLanguageCode()));
            if(!delLangId.equalsIgnoreCase(countryLanguage.getLanguage().getLanguageCode())){
                tempCountryLangList.add(countryLanguage);
            }
        }
        setCountryLanguageList(tempCountryLangList);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

addCountry.js

```
function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
var el = radio.form.elements;
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
        el[i].checked = false;
    }
}
radio.checked = true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of this:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{countryBean.deleteRow}" immediate="true" update="@form" process="@this">
```

When clicking the button, you will transmit the form with the checkboxes. But because of `process="@this"` you will not convert/validate/store any inputs. The only thing that will get processed is the button itself. After that, because of `update="@form"` the whole form (including the table with the checkboxes) will be re-rendered. But with the *old* values.

Thus the solution is to either change `process="@this"` to `@form` or to add Ajax functionality to store the new values of each checkbox every time the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with bean scope. If scenario is like:
Precondition:
-Table are just showed.
Scenario:
-Select some checkbox.
-Delete row
Current result
-Selected checkbox is unchecked.

So after delete row you propably reinit view so all data get default state.
Try to change your scope to View(CDI) or Session.